# Are there any online search engines for buses in Southeast Asia? I wish to plan a bus trip in Thailand

Tags: online-resources, planning, buses, thailand, southeast-asia

I am planning a trip in Thailand. As public buses or so called government buses seem to be more reliable I'm focusing on these bus operators.

The website [12Go](https://12go.asia/en) is good for researching which bus I have to take.
Is there any other website which gives more details like where it stops during a trip and so on?

There also is [ThaiRoute](http://www.thairoute.com/) but it is only in Thai.
Of interest are also the bus operator websites.

Answer (score 1):

Most websites for regional bus companies are in Thai and payment is often limited to ATM, bank deposits and such, not international credit cards.

Most list buses schedules from A to B, without much detail on other stops enroute.  You often have to guess at intermediate stops and then compare timetables to see if bus numbers match.

Long Haul bus routes tend to pick up at A, with perhaps a stop or two close by and then head for B, with a mid-trip break at some food stop.  As an example a bus from Chiang Mai to Bangkok will likely stop at Lamphun and maybe Lampang to pick up more passengers and then head for Bangkok.  They will take a food / stretch your legs break at Thoen or Tak.

Is there a need for knowing where it stops or simply curiosity?

Comment: Yes simply curiosity. I wanted to know where the bus stops so I could research if it might be a good idea to stay there for a day or two and keep on traveling the next day with the same bus line.
What would really help is a map with all the bus stations for government buses in Thailand or available destinations of each bus station to plan a round trip.

Comment: Most every town in Thailand has "government" bus service of one form or another (even tiny villages often have flag stop service).  So a map of Thailand would be a map of all the destinations for "government" buses.  Buses tend to come in two forms, long haul and provincial.  Long haul buses go from A to B, without much in the way of intermediate stops.  Provincial buses stop every where, but usually stay within a province or neighboring provinces.

Answer (score 0):

12go asia has it all, stops and maps. you can hop off anywhere, but hop on mostly in provincial centers or large towns. unless you solve local logistic, there is no point in this kind of hops. how do you want to go from the provincial bus station, and where? they don't rent motorbikes there on every corner, actually don't rent at all. no taxis.  no tuk tuk neither, mostly. imagine a wat in 35 km away from town, how do you get there? how do you get back? this issue is more difficult than bus hop on hop off :) especially provided most of long hauls really go bkk - distant place with no stops, interprovincials will stop anywhere you ask.